# Buscar el texto de un link

Tags: javascript, dom

Necesito buscar todos los link que en su texto tenga escrito FALLO, lo intente con el método document.getElementById pero el problema es que el id cambia en cada etiqueta

Adjunto etiqueta de ejemplo

```
<a title="Consultar" href="obtenerConsulta=20210505" target="_BLANK">FALLO</a>
```

Espero que algún sabio me pueda ayudar muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Debes obtener todos los enlaces y filtrar para dejar solo los que contienen el texto. Tal vez [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42907920/2412893) (en inglés) te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias las respuestas me funcionaron para solucionar el problema

Answer (score 2):

Sería algo así:

```js
const results = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].filter(el => el.text === 'FALLO');
```

Ojo con las diversas funciones que se usan:

- [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll): para encontrar todos los elementos que cumplan el criterio de selección, en este caso la etiqueta `a`.
- [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): para establecer un criterio de filtrado y solo considerar los elementos que cumplan con ese criterio.